# Why can't I use put Render Layers in a node group? (Compositor)

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, render-layers

When I try to create a node group that includes the Render Layers node, I get an error saying it can't create a group with that node. Is there a reason why or some way around it? I don't want to have to plug the input into every single copy of my node group.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/tp2bV2H.png]

Answer (score -1):

Probably because that is a group in its own. A render group. And so Blender just will not let you do that.

Comment: This answer implies that groups cannot be put into groups. It is not true. You can have groups inside other groups without any problems.